# why does putObject throw AmazonS3Exception when using PutObjectRequest, but works fine without PutObjectRequest?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am writing a Java method that takes 3 string parameters: bucketName, objectKey, objectContent. The method then puts the object into the bucket. The following code works with no problems.

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(REGION).build();
s3.putObject(bucketName, objectKey, content);
```

Now I want to set a content type for the objects, because I will be using the method to store e.g. "text/plain" or "text/xml" files. So I use the following code.

```
    AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(REGION).build();
    byte[] fileContentBytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    InputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContentBytes);
    ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
    metaData.setContentType(contentType);
    metaData.setContentLength(fileContentBytes.length);
    PutObjectRequest putObjReq = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey, content);
    putObjReq.setMetadata(metaData);
    s3.putObject(putObjReq);
```

When I run this code, I get an exception, as listed below. Why?

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The website redirect location must have a prefix of 'http://' or 'https://' or '/'. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRedirectLocation; Request ID: F8032DFF52EBF6F2; S3 Extended Request ID: vZX1/oTjeWU0Fok6twiyB5mEi2d0GDXYWT+akeETrapXo9CUbG+DgcabAaiFVlGXOu072vGghD4=), S3 Extended Request ID: vZX1/oTjeWU0Fok6twiyB5mEi2d0GDXYWT+akeETrapXo9CUbG+DgcabAaiFVlGXOu072vGghD4=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4926)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4872)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:390)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:5806)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1794)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1754)
    at util.DataUtils.saveContentToS3(DataUtils.java:155)
    at builder.SEOGenerator.main(SEOGenerator.java:53)
```

I should note that I use this S3 bucket to host a static website. I use CloudFront in front of S3 and then Route 53 for my domain. My S3 bucket policy is as follows.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy - my-domain.com",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from my domain",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.my-domain.com/*",
                        "http://my-domain.com/*",
                        "https://www.my-domain.com/*",
                        "https://my-domain.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 different ways to call the `PutObjectRequest` constructor. You're using this one:

```
PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, String redirectLocation)
```

So, your 'content' is being treated as a redirect location, hence that error.

I think your intent is to use this one instead:

```
PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input, ObjectMetadata metadata)
```

Which means you'd have to do something like:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(REGION).build();
byte[] fileContentBytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContentBytes);
ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
metaData.setContentType(contentType);
metaData.setContentLength(fileContentBytes.length);
PutObjectRequest putObjReq = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey, in, metaData);
s3.putObject(putObjReq);
```